# SQL SelfJoin + Left Outer JOIN Calendar

Tags: sql, database, calendar

I got a SelfJoin query

```
;WITH t as 
(
SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION,DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', CONVERT(VARCHAR,REPLACE(dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Doc_Time,'24:00:00','23:59:59'),102)), CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.DIM_TIME_USAGE.DATE)) ASC) AS Rowy,
 dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.FACT_MEASUREMENT_KEY,
  dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Doc_Number,
  dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Created_By,
  dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Text,
  dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Doc_Time,
  dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Date_Loaded,
  dbo.DIM_VC_MEASURE.VALUATION_CODE_AND_DESC,
  dbo.DIM_TIME_USAGE.DATE,
  dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION,
  dbo.DIM_VC_MEASURE.VALUATION_CODE,
CONVERT(VARCHAR,REPLACE(dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Doc_Time,'24:00:00','23:59:59'),102) AS TIME,
DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', CONVERT(VARCHAR,REPLACE(dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Doc_Time,'24:00:00','23:59:59'),102)), CONVERT(DATETIME, dbo.DIM_TIME_USAGE.DATE)) AS DATUM
FROM
  dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ INNER JOIN dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT ON (dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.PROJECT_TECH_OBJ_KEY=dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ.PROJECT_TECH_OBJ_KEY)
   INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_TIME_USAGE ON (dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.TIME_KEY=dbo.DIM_TIME_USAGE.TIME_KEY)
   INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_VC_MEASURE ON (dbo.DIM_VC_MEASURE.VALUATION_CODE_KEY=dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.VALUATION_CODE_KEY)
WHERE
   dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT.Measurement_Position  = 'AVAILABILITY'
   AND
   dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION IN ('XXX','YYY','ZZZ')
     )
select t.*, tprev.DATUM AS PRE_DATUM, tprev.VALUATION_CODE AS PRE_CODE, DATEDIFF (minute,tprev.DATUM, t.DATUM) AS DELTA_MIN
from t join
     t tprev
     on tprev.rowy = t.rowy - 1 AND tprev.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION = t.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION ;
```

This will return a set of field

```
FUNTIONAL LOC   DATUM   CODE    PRE_DATUM   PRE_CODE   (-> Other fields)
XXX             01/07/2015  A   06/06/2015  Y
XXX             05/07/2015  B   01/07/2015  A
XXX             10/07/2015  C   05/07/2015  B
YYY             03/07/2015  B   15/06/2015  K
YYY             09/07/2015  C   03/07/2015  B
YYY             15/07/2015  A   09/07/2015  C
```

Now I would like to create an outer join with calendar (image from 01/07 to 10/07) dates and obtain something like:

```
FUNTIONAL LOC   DATUM   CODE    PRE_DATUM   PRE_CODE
XXX             01/07/2015  A   06/06/2015  Y
XXX             02/07/2015      06/06/2015  Y
XXX             03/07/2015      06/06/2015  Y
XXX             04/07/2015      06/06/2015  Y
XXX             05/07/2015  B   01/07/2015  A
XXX             06/07/2015      01/07/2015  A
XXX             07/07/2015      01/07/2015  A
XXX             08/07/2015      01/07/2015  A
XXX             09/07/2015      01/07/2015  A
XXX             10/07/2015  C   05/07/2015  B
YYY             01/07/2015      15/06/2015  K
YYY             02/07/2015      15/06/2015  K
YYY             03/07/2015  B   15/06/2015  K
YYY             09/07/2015  C   03/07/2015  B
YYY             10/07/2015      03/07/2015  B
```

Basically when NO code is found on a calendar data use the prev one.

Any suggestion/idea?
Thanks in advance.

S.

Comment: So do you actually have, for example, `02/07/2015` for FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION = 'XXX' in the CTE?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, your result set doesn't correspond to your query.  The result set has more columns than the query produces.

Comment: Hello, I'm using SQL as a Database. Result has more columns but I've just remarked ones that are crucial for my desired output. But I can post all the complete query if needed and necessary. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the following steps:

- define this intermediate result AND the "calendar" table as a chain of the `WITH` statement
- perform a `LEFT JOIN` of the "calendar" table and the intermediate result defined on the point above (some DB requires specifying `LEFT OUTER JOIN`)
- perform the row-numbering join technique again on the result of the two steps above

Example of the first two steps:

```
WITH t as ( ... ),
t2 as ( select t.*, tprev.time
  from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.rowy = t.rowy - 1 ),
cal as ( ... )
SELECT *
FROM cal
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON cal.DATUM = t2.DATUM;
```

Please notice that:

- the intermediate result of your original question is now defined as `t2`
- in the final result you mocked, you can't keep the values of DATUM as coming from the original intermediate result as reported in your question, because values are missing and I suppose what you want is indeed to display all calendar values instead
- the third point of the steps above can be obtained by performing same technique as you illustrated in the original question.
- you will need to specify the ordering in the final results.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `cross join` the result of your query with `calender` table. Something like this

```
WITH t
     AS (SELECT Row_number()
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY Q2.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION)    AS Rowy,
                Q1.FACT_MEASUREMENT_KEY,
                CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), Q1.Doc_Time, 102) AS TIME
         FROM   dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ Q2
                INNER JOIN dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT Q1
                        ON Q1.PROJECT_TECH_OBJ_KEY = Q2.PROJECT_TECH_OBJ_KEY
         WHERE  Q1.Measurement_Position = 'XXX'),
     result
     AS (SELECT t.*,
                tprev.time
         FROM   t
                LEFT JOIN t tprev
                       ON tprev.rowy = t.rowy - 1),
     date_cook
     AS (SELECT FUNTIONAL_LOC,
                c.dates,
                PRE_DATUM,
                PRE_CODE
         FROM   result r
                CROSS JOIN calender c
         WHERE  c.dates BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND '2015-07-10')
SELECT dc.FUNTIONAL_LOC,
       dc.dates           AS DATUM,
       Isnull(r.code, '') AS code,
       dc.PRE_DATUM,
       dc.PRE_CODE
FROM   date_cook dc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN result r
                    ON dc.FUNTIONAL_LOC= r.FUNTIONAL_LOC
                       AND dc.dates = r.DATUM
                       AND dc.PRE_DATUM = r.PRE_DATUM
                       AND dc.PRE_CODE = r.PRE_CODE
```

Comment: Hello Indian, thank you: just tryed but not success.Got Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
SQLState:  S1000
ErrorCode: 156 Can you please explain me how to use Calendar table? I've updated with all detailed query as per suggested by Gordon.

Comment: I've tryied again and I've obtained duplicates, (all FLOC x Day records are multiplied per all hits in the time slice)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed by creating a LEFT JOIN (Calendar records to Result records): In this case I'm avoiding cartesian products obtained by the CROSS join and all duplicated.
For the PRE-CODE I'm thinking to use self join on the Result table:

```
WITH t as (
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Q2.FUNCTIONAL_LOCATION) AS Rowy,
             Q1.FACT_MEASUREMENT_KEY,
             CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), Q1.Doc_Time, 102) AS TIME
      FROM dbo.DIM_PROJECT_TECH_OBJ Q2 INNER JOIN
           dbo.FACT_MEASUREMENT Q1
           ON Q1.PROJECT_TECH_OBJ_KEY = Q2.PROJECT_TECH_OBJ_KEY
      WHERE Q1.Measurement_Position = 'XXX'
     )
select t.*, tprev.time
from t left join
     t tprev
     on tprev.rowy = t.rowy - 1;
```